# How can I rescale the the size of the image for the clusters to plot properly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial

I'm having this issue where I'm trying to properly fit this Miami map to correctly display my clusters of miami house prices. Can someone please help? I tried multiple rescaling methods, but I couldn't find a solution.

Heres my code:

```
miami = mpimg.imread('/Users/zahidlaguna/Downloads/Miami.png')
img_height, img_width = miami.shape[:2]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.scatter(X_train['LONGITUDE'], X_train['LATITUDE'], c = fits[3].labels_, cmap = 'Set1', alpha = 0.5)
ax.imshow(miami, extent = [-80.5, -79.5, 25.5, 26.5], alpha = 0.5)
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.title('Miami Housing Clusters')
plt.show()
```

The output of the code:

[image: Resulting plot]

I tried multiple approaches to re-scaling just to see how it could look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks okay, but from what I can tell by eyeballing a map, your coordinates for the `extent` of the map are wrong. It looks like they should be about `[-80.329, -80.131, 25.694, 25.872]` — but do check these; you should obviously use the most exact values you can.

If you want to avoid this kind of inaccuracy, you might want to check out [`geopandas` and `folium`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/plotting_with_folium.html), and other tools for handling and visualizing geospatial data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing might be related to the proper alignment and scaling of the map image with your data points.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mping

miami = mpimg.imread('/Users/zahidlaguna/Downloads/Miami.png')
img_height, img_width = miami.shape[:2]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.scatter(X_train['LONGITUDE'], X_train['LATITUDE'], c = fits[3].labels_, cmap = 'Set1', alpha = 0.5)
ax.imshow(miami, extent = [-80.5, -79.5, 25.5, 26.5], alpha = 0.5)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.title('Miami Housing Clusters')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Changing the aspect ratio of the plot does not change the data space.